# Replace transpose method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, prawn, transpose

I have the following code:

```
table([
          ["UnitID", "First Name", "NPS Score", "Comments"],
          *[invite_unitid_arr, invite_name_arr, nps_score_integers_final, comment_arr]
          .transpose.reject{ |x| x[3].empty? }
      ], :position => :center, :column_widths => {0 => 50, 1 => 60, 2 => 60, 3 => 40, 4 => 150}) do
  row(0).style :background_color => 'C0C0C0'
end
```

I am calling `transpose` on an array of arrays. I am refactoring this code and I now have an array of model objects:

```
array = Model.all
```

How can I rewrite the above, saying "Loop through each model (Model1, Model2, etc.) and create a row with the attributes unit_id,first_name,nps_score,comment like so: `Model1[:unit_id],Model1[:first_name],Model1[:nps_score],Model1[:comment]`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an array of objects like this:

```
my_models = [ <MyModel id: 1, unit_id: 123, first_name: "Xxx", nps_score: 100, ...>,
              <MyModel id: 2, unit_id: 456, first_name: "Yyy", nps_score: 200, ...>,
              ...
            ]
```

And you want an array like this:

```
[ [ "UnitID", "First Name", "NPS Score", "Comments" ],
  [ 123,      "Xxx",        100,         "..."      ],
  [ 456,      "Yyy",        200,         "..."      ],
  ...
]
```

All you really need to do is this:

```
headers = [ "UnitID", "First Name", "NPS Score", "Comments" ]

data = my_models.map do |model|
  [ model.unit_id, model.first_name, model.nps_score, model.comments ]
end

rows = [ headers, *data ]
```

Or...

```
data = my_models.map do |model|
         model.attributes.values_at(:unit_id, :first_name, :nps_score, :comments)
       end
```

(Either way you could make this a one-liner, but mind your code's readability.)

Of course, it's always best to select only the columns you're going to use, so you could just do this (adding whatever `where`, `order` etc. calls you need):

```
my_models = MyModel.select([ :unit_id, :first_name, :nps_score, :comments ]).where(...)
data = my_models.map(&:attributes)
# => [ [ 123, "Xxx", 100, "..." ],
#      [ 456, "Yyy", 200, "..." ],
#      ...
#    ]
```

In Rails 4 the [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method takes multiple arguments, making this even easier:

```
data = MyModel.where(...).pluck(:unit_id, :first_name, :nps_score, :comments)
# => [ [ 123, "Xxx", 100, "..." ],
#      [ 456, "Yyy", 200, "..." ],
#      ...
#    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what are you trying to achieve here, but it seems that you are looking for `pluck` method. Since rails 4 it allows you to pluck multiple columns at once (and by default will pluck all columns). So it seems that:

```
Model.pluck(:unit_id, :first_name, :nps_score, :comment)
```

Is what you are looking for - and is actually much better as it is not instantiating new objects and makes just one call to db. . It will return 2d array, one row for each model. If you rather prefer have different values of same column, add transpose on the above.